# AWS Disallow Actions as a Root User with SCP

Tags: security, amazon-iam

Aws best practices recommends to secure aws accounts by disallowing account access with root user credentials.

this is the template they provide with

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GRRESTRICTROOTUSER",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:root"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The way I understand this is that if I attach this to my account, I will not have permissions anymore as root. But I do. And I if wouldn't it means I'd lock myself out from any operation.

However, if I add this to another account created, the permissions for that account and any other IAM users in that account are not having permissions anymore.

I am confused. here are the docs for [Disallow Creation of Access Keys for the Root User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/strongly-recommended-guardrails.html#disallow-root-access-keys)

**Update**

The way I am implementing the policy is through Organizations SCP.

I think the policy is supposed to be implemented through Control Tower.
That is why I think what I am trying to achieve is not possible. I am still not clear about it, therefore not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that your account where this SCP is not working is your management (formerly called master) account.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html):

> **Important:**
> SCPs don't affect users or roles in the management account. They
> affect only the member accounts in your organization.

Comment: nice one. good read. I need to investigate a bit further, before i mark the answer. I would like other users to put their opinions too